# Path does not get displayed

Tags: wpf, path, geometry, shapes

I have content presenter with contented bound to a shape from the templated parent. When the shape is an ellipse, the content presenter shows the ellipse, however when I change the Shape to path and set the data property to ellipse geometry nothing gets displayed, I am setting the stroke and fill same as on the ellipse shape. Here is how I am constructing the path:

```
        Shape = new Path();
        Shape.Data = new EllipseGeometry();
        Shape.Fill = Brushes.Transparent;
        Shape.Stroke = Brushes.CadetBlue;
```

However when I replace it with this it does work (Assuming Shape is of type Ellipse):

```
        Shape = new Ellipse();
        Shape.Fill = Brushes.Transparent;
        Shape.Stroke = Brushes.CadetBlue;
```

The reason why I want to use a path with a geometry as data, is because I want to test intersection on the shape, but I don't know how to get the geometry of a shape object, where as if the shape is of type `Path` I can test against Shape.Data.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can try Geometry.Parse("values in points") and assign return value to Shape.Data

Answer (score 0):

The `EllipseGeometry` behaves a bit differently to the `Ellipse` shape. Its dimensions are defined by its `RadiusX` and `RadiusY` properties, which by default are `0`, thus nothing is drawn. You can set these as follows:

```
Shape.Data = new EllipseGeometry { RadiusX = 1.0, RadiusY = 1.0 };
```

However, this still probably won't display as your `Ellipse` does. The `Ellipse` also defaults to `Stretch.Fill` for its `Stretch` property, but the `Path` has `Stretch.None`. If you change this, they should look the same:

```
Shape.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
```

You can play around with the other properties of the `Path` and the `EllipseGeometry` to size, orient, and locate it correctly.